# Device admin app for rooted android

Tags: android, mdm, android-os-handler

> We have our own rooted hardware device with android OS 7.0

We are building an app for that device. We have to restrict the users to performing some of the actions who will purchase that device. Here are the list of actions We want user to be restricted to perform on the device through the app.

1. Stop installing/uninstalling any other apps from OS.
2. On/off wifi
3. Pair Bluetooth
4. Change wallpaper

Basic idea behind is to **make** an app which will be the **system app** and will **restrict user** from the things mentioned above.

Is this possible to make such app? Looking for help in any of the above tasks. Thanks

Comment: There is a way .Take a look at the device admin api https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin. you can create an app that comes preinstalled when you ship out the device to buyers .And this app can enforce all the restrictions you want to apply through device policies.

Answer (score 2):

Shor answer: NO. 
Here is why;

The Android operation System is based on permissions, and no app can restrict that actions even with the users' permission. The reason for this is because of the Android App Layer that provides all the capabilities you described above.

The only way you can do such thing is to Customize the ROM of the CellPhone. In this case, you can override the functions that allow the user to use such services.